# Combining 4 Boolean Values In A Simple Function Or Condition

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have 4 boolean values.

```
next_is_left
next_is_right
next_is_above
next_is_below
```

First I want to check if they are **all** `true`. Then I want to check if **one** of them is `false`. Then if **two** of them are `false`, then **three** or if **all** are `false`.

I wonder how I can fit this problem in one simple if condition / function. Thanks.

Comment: `[next_is_left,
next_is_right,
next_is_above,
next_is_below].filter(Boolean).length`

Comment: How should I understand this line ??

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: That expression will give you the number of `true` values. If they're all true, it will result in 4, if they're all false it will result in 0, etc.

Comment: @DavidMihal nope, filter doesnt do that, filter returns an array so if you do  filter(true)  it will return an array cointaining the true values, and by doing array.length you will get the count of true values

Comment: @LPZadkiel yep, but he was asking for an explanation of the whole expression, which returns a number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 switch(next_is_left + next_is_right + next_is_above + next_is_below){
   case 0:
     console.log("all false");
     break;
   case 1:
     console.log("one true");
     break;
   case 2:
     console.log("two true");
     break;
   case 3:
     console.log("one false");
     break;
   case 0:
     console.log("all true");
     break;

 }
```

Just add the booleans up.

Answer (score 0):

What about counting the number of true values and using switch case to deal with the result?

```js
let next_is_left = false;
let next_is_right = true;
let next_is_above = true;
let next_is_below = false;

switch (getNumTrue(next_is_left, next_is_right, next_is_above, next_is_below)) {
    case 0:
        console.log(`All false`);
        break;
    case 1:
        console.log(`1 true, 3 false`);
        break;
    case 2:
        console.log(`2 true, 2 false`);
        break;
    case 3:
        console.log(`3 true, 1 false`);
        break;
    case 4:
        console.log(`All true`);
        break;
}    

function getNumTrue() {
    let i, numTrue;
    numTrue = 0;
    for (i = arguments.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
        numTrue += arguments[i] ? 1 : 0;
    }
    return numTrue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `every` method for Array to check whether all of them are true or false, and filter to see how many

```
var next_is_left = true;
var next_is_right = true;
var next_is_above = true;
var next_is_below = true;

var sides = [
  next_is_left,
  next_is_right,
  next_is_above,
  next_is_below,
];

sides.every(n => n === true); // checks if all true
sides.every(n => n === false); // checks if all false
sides.filter(n => n === false).length; // returns number of false variables
```

Answer (score 0):

Use arrays to do the work.

```
var booleans = [
  next_is_left
  next_is_right
  next_is_above
  next_is_below
];

var holdsTrue = function(arg) { return arg; };
var holdsFalse = function(arg) { return !arg; };


var theyAreAllTrue = booleans.filter(holdsTrue).length === booleans.length;
var oneOfThemIsFalse = booleans.filter(holdsFalse).length > 0;
var twoOfThemIsFalse = booleans.filter(holdsFalse).length > 1;
var threeOfThemIsFalse = booleans.filter(holdsFalse).length > 2;
var theyAreAllFalse = booleans.filter(holdsFalse).length === booleans.length;
```

Also with lodash you have every, some, negate, identity and size

```
var theyAreAllTrue = every(booleans, identity)
var theyAreAllFalse = every(booleans, negate(identity));
var numberOfFalseOnes = size(filter(booleans, negate(identity)))
var numberOfTrueOnes = size(filter(booleans, identity))

var oneOfThemIsTrue = some(booleans, identity)
var oneOfThemIsFalse = some(booleans, negate(identity))
```